# How can i use a specific proprety for each bean call in Spring

Tags: spring, parameters, dynamically-generated

I'm developing an application using spring . I have a bean that i need to call multiple times but for each call i need to change the  properties values dynamically . Is there  a way to do this .

I had an idea to set the bean  properties as an array ,in eatch array i put the parameters that i want to use . For example array[0] contains the params of the first call , array[1] params of the second call,... is it possible to do that ?

Here is a code sample :

```
<bean class="Dummy2">
    <!-- or a list of values -->
    <property name="foos"> 
        <util:list>
            <value>A,b,c</value>
            <value>X,y,z</value>
            <value>1,2,3</value>
            <value>7,8,9</value>
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

the setter

```
@Override
public void setFoo(list<String[]> args) {
...
}
```

If any one have a better idea or a usefull idea i will be grateful

Thank You

This is the propreties of the bean that calls the beans

```
<property name="activities">
      <list>
        <ref bean="1"/> //Calling bean 1
        <ref bean="2"/> //Calling bean 2
        <ref bean="1"/> //Calling bean 1 again
        <ref bean="2"/>//Calling bean 2 again
        <ref bean="2"/>
      </list>
    </property>
```

i need to use different parameters for each call (call the setter with different values)

Comment: If it always are those values, from 0 to end, then it looks perfectly fine.

Comment: no the values are provided by the user , and the calls for the bean are managed by Spring , so i call the bean 3 times but it always use the same parameters , what i want is for each call i use different parameters that i get from the user :)

Comment: Can you add a code example?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your flow... Where are the "parameters from the users"? And how is the bean used at runtime? Not trying to be picky. Just trying to understand :)

Comment: the parameters i get them from an external file . the are other classes that launches the beans , i cant provide the code just i posted the part that is calling the beans

Answer (score 1):

Would using Spring's PostConstruct annotation on an initialiser method on your 'master' bean be useful? You could use simple setter methods to inject both the list of beans and the list of configurations into the master bean, and in the init method (annotated with @PostConstruct) configure each bean correctly.
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with AOP you can use aspect to do this using @Before Advice to set your method properties before calling it